# .htaccess redirects - I am completely lost

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to create some redirects using htaccess but I am quite a bit overwhelmed with it all. So here it goes.

The NEW domain is hosted on my hosting account but there is no site built. I just want to use the domain for "easier" branding. Here is what I am trying to achieve.

I want people who go to my NewDomain.com be redirected to an external site: blog.OldDomain.com/podcast/

I also want to create redirects to upcoming new posts. For example, I want to send people to NewDomain.com/1 and have them redirected to blog.OldDomain.com/episode1. Then NewDomain.com/2 would redirect to blog.OldDomain.com/episode2, etc.

I hope someone can help me with this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok nevermind, I found the solution. Simply created

Redirect 301 /index.html http://olddomain. com/podcast/

and I will add new lines as I create new pages ;)